# ¿como puedo mostrar el numero siguiente guardado en mysql en spring boot + jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Saludos a la comunidad

Tengo un inconveniente al poder encontrar una solución a mi problema si alguien puede apoyarme en la solución es poder mostrar es el numero siguiente guardado en mi base de datos 
el numero es 1 y quiero que me muestre 2 en el formulario

dejo el código 
en el repository

```
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Long> {

    @Query("Select  f from Factura f order by codigo Desc")
    Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro();

    @Query("Select  Count(*) from Factura ")
    Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

}
```

en el service

```
public interface FacturaService {


    Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro();


    Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

    List<Factura> facturaLista();

    Long numeroFactura();

}
```

en el serviceiml

```
@Service
public class FacturaServiceImpl implements FacturaService {

    private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;


    @Autowired
    public FacturaServiceImpl(FacturaRepository facturaRepository) {

        this.facturaRepository = facturaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro() {

        return facturaRepository.obtenerUltimoRegistro();
    }

    @Override
    public Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura() {


        return facturaRepository.obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Factura> facturaLista() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return facturaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

en el controller:

```
@PostMapping("/ventas")
public String numeracion(Model model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("numFactura1") Long numFactura,
        @ModelAttribute("facturas") Factura factura) {

    numFactura=2L;

    try {
       comprobante(model, numFactura);
        numFactura = Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact());

        numFactura = facturaService.obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

        if (numFactura <= 0 || numFactura == null) {
            comprobante(model,  numFactura);
            numFactura = Long.valueOf(1);

            model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numFactura);

            return "venta/ventas";
        } else {
            comprobante(model, numFactura);

            factura = facturaService.obtenerUltimoRegistro();
            numFactura = Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact() + 1);

            model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numFactura);
            return "venta/ventas";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }

    model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numFactura);

    return "/venta/ventas";
}

@ModelAttribute
public void comprobante(Model model,Long numFactura) {
    model.addAttribute("numFactura",numFactura);

}
```

en el jsp.

```
<form:form action="${path}/venta/numeracion" method="POST"  modelAttribute="<facturas>,<numFactura>">

    <label for="numFactura" class="control-label col-md-1">Numero</label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numFactura" value="${numFactura1}" autofocus ></input>
                            </div>

</form:form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otro caso es cuando cambio el codigo en el controller en la siguiente linea de codigo

```
@ModelAttribute
public void comprobante(Model model,Long numFactura) {

    Factura factura=new Factura();


    numFactura =  Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact());
    model.addAttribute("numFactura",numFactura);
}
```

me genera el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.proyecto.app.controller.FacturaController.comprobante(FacturaController.java:112) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:142) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.ventura.app.filter.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.ventura.app.filter.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 112 de `FacturaController`? Esa es la que esta disparando el `NullPointerException`.

Comment: es numFaxtura=Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya  pude solucionar dejo el codigo

en el repository

@Query("Select  f from Factura f order by codigo Desc")
    Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro();

```
@Query("Select  Count(*) from Factura ")
Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

@Query("Select  f from Factura f where numfact=:numfact")
Factura findFacturabyNumero(Long numfact);
```

en el service

Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro();

```
Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

List<Factura> facturaLista();

Long nextNro();

Factura findFacturabyNumero(Long numfact);
```

en el serviceImpl

private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;

```
@Autowired
public FacturaServiceImpl(FacturaRepository facturaRepository) {

    this.facturaRepository = facturaRepository;
}

@Override
public Factura obtenerUltimoRegistro() {

    return facturaRepository.obtenerUltimoRegistro();
}

@Override
public Long obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura() {


    return facturaRepository.obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();
}

@Override
public List<Factura> facturaLista() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return facturaRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Long nextNro() {
    facturaRepository.findAll();
    return (long) (facturaLista().size()+1);
}

@Override
public Factura findFacturabyNumero(Long numfact) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return facturaRepository.findFacturabyNumero(numfact);
}
```

en el controller

```
private FacturaService facturaService;

@Autowired
public FacturaController(FacturaService facturaService) {

    this.facturaService = facturaService;
}



@PostMapping("/ventas")
public String numeracion(Model model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("numfact") Long numfact,
        @ModelAttribute("facturas") Factura factura) {

    numfact=2L;

    try {
       comprobante(model,numfact, new Factura());

        numfact = Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact());

        numfact = facturaService.obtenerTotalRegistrosFactura();

        if (numfact <= 0 || numfact == null) {
        //  comprobante(model, new Factura(), numFactura);
            numfact = Long.valueOf(1);

            model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numfact);

            return "venta/ventas";
        } else {
            //comprobante(model, new Factura(), numFactura);

            factura = facturaService.obtenerUltimoRegistro();
            numfact = Long.valueOf(factura.getNumfact() + 1);

            model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numfact);
            return "venta/ventas";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }

    model.addAttribute("numFactura1", numfact);

    return "/venta/ventas";
}
```

@ModelAttribute
    public void comprobante(Model model,Long numfact,Factura factura) {

```
    numfact=facturaService.nextNro();

    model.addAttribute("numFactura",numfact);

}
```

en el jsp

,">

```
<label for="numFactura" class="control-label col-md-1">Numero</label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numFactura" value="${numFactura}" autofocus ></input>
                            </div>
```